# Check for inline styling added after page load to run function?

Tags: jquery

I have a function for a website that adds dashes to a date. It runs onload. Unfortunately, it runs for an application where on a submit, if X condition isn't met (in this case, the date needs to be the span of a minimum 2 years), another field shows that was previously hidden for a prior employment record to be added.

The problem is that when the field shows the function I declared on page load does not work on this function. However from inspecting the code, I noticed that there is an inline styling added for `style="display: block"` to the element. However, it only uses the classes `employment-form loan-form hide` - and hide still shows. The full:

```
<div class="employment-form loan-form hide " style="display: block;">
```

Where previously, `style="display: block"` does not show.

I am trying to work around the confines of this functionality because my job uses a vendor for this and this is actually being phased out so it is no longer supported by them as we prepare to move to a different one.

Is there a way that I can use jQuery to check to see if an element gets inline styling added and if it does, then run a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes to the `style` attribute, then take action if its style has changed to `display: block`.

To create the observer:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
    // your logic here
});
```

Then to hook it up and watch the element for attribute changes:

```js
const element = $("employment-form.loan-form.hide")[0]; // [0] to get the raw element
observer.observe(element, {
    attributes: true
});
```

Note that you don't need jQuery for this, you could use `querySelector` to get the element instead:

```js
const element = document.querySelector("employment-form.loan-form.hide");
```

At that point, changing any attribute on the element will trigger your callback.

So for instance:

```js
const element = $("employment-form.loan-form.hide")[0]; // [0] to get the raw element
const observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
    if (element.style.display === "block") {
        // It has the block style now
    }
});
observer.observe(element, {
    attributes: true
});
```

When you don't need to watch it anymore, call [`disconnect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect) on the observer.

```js
observer.disconnect();
```